# Calculate and display difference between two dates using moment.js in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, momentjs

I am trying to calculate and display number of days between two dates in my React app.

However, while doing so, I am having issues converting the date from my date picker to a string? Do I even need to convert the date to a string before calculating? Here is what I have.

```
var numberOfDays = function({props.startDatePicker},{props.endDatePicker}){
    return { 
        moment({props.startDatePicker}.diff({props.endDatePicker}, 'days'));
    };
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Where should I place this code?

Comment: I'd start by making sure your syntax is right. What you've posted here is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call `.diff()` on a moment object.  Try moving the close parenthesis around `{props.startDatePicker}`

```
moment({props.startDatePicker}).diff({props.endDatePicker}, 'days');
```

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Comment: There is no need in adding `{` `}` as the whole `moment(` expression is inside such braces:
`moment(props.startDatePicker).diff(props.endDatePicker, 'days');`

Comment: @lunochkin yeah I think you are right.  I just left them to avoid confusion so that OP could see the main issue with their syntax.